# how to resize horizontally a screen region

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I am using `screen` to split my terminals but I would like to be able to resize the horizontal dimension of the split screens.

If I do `C-a :resize 10` I only change the vertical dimension to 10 lines. How do I achieve the same but for the horizontal dimension?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

At least on Debian and Ubuntu, the `resize` command, when applied to a full height region performs a horizontal resizing.

If it works for you, then first split vertically, next perform a resizing of the width, then split horizontally.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: @pedrosaurio: I reformulated the answer.

Comment: I tried `C-a :resize -h 10` and it worked. Before you recommended `C-a :resize -v 10` .... I guess your suggestion was right since the beginning  but we both got confused with h's and v's. Thanks!

Comment: resize applies to the current region, please try to post screen shot, and show which region you cannot resize.
Also a note from GNU Screen web page on the resize command under Bugs, "many of the resize commands will not work reliably with a complicated screen layout"

Comment: Resize **by percent**: `:resize 50%`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Here are some more commands: C-a :resize -h +10 increases the size and C-a :resize -h -10 decreases the size.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use resize command intuitively.
Just type `C-a : resize +10` to increase size and you can use -10 as well. 
You can use the same command for both vertical and horizontal window resizing

Comment: But ***how*** does one resize horizontally?  (Hint: the other answer seems to know.)

Comment: The above command seems to work on both scenarios, just try

Comment: Do `C-a |` to split side by side panels and `C-a : resize +10` then you'll have width adjustment. If you do `C-a S` as first command instead, you'll have height adjustment. Also works with negative number on `:resize` command. I consider this answer the best because solve for all OS not just Debian (I'm in Manjaro), requiring only usage of `screen`

Answer (score 5):

From [the `screen` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Resize.html):

> Command:
>
> ```
> resize [-h|-v|-b|-l|-p] [ [+|-]n[%] | = | max | min | _ | 0 ]
> ```
>
> Resize the current region. The space will be removed from or added to the surrounding regions depending on the order of the splits. The available options for resizing are
>
> - `-h` (horizontal)
> - `-v` (vertical)
> - `-b` (both)
> - `-l` (local to layer), and
> - `-p` (perpendicular).

So `C-a :resize -h 10` should work.